# Setting the Security protocol for SimpleHTTPServer in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, simplehttpserver

I have a python server using BaseHTTPServer and SimpleHTTPServer to respond to clients over SSL. I am able to use a generated SSL cert to secure connections, but am unable to choose which security protocol to use (e.g. SSLv1, TLS 1.2, SSLv3).

Is there any way to specify the security protocol to use within these modules, or is there a python module that I could use instead to provide similar functionality and be able to specify security protocol?

Comment: Are you using Python OpenSSL to provide the TLS connection?

Comment: I'm using M2Crypto and tlslite. Is there a functional difference between them? I need M2crypto for generating the cert, and tlslite is to wrap the socket.

Comment: How about the way [this guy](http://www.gnucitizen.org/blog/python-ssl-mitm-proxy-and-more/) does it?

Comment: It looks like tlslite doesn't allow that - but if you use OpenSSL directly, you should be able to do it the way I linked.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks. I'm hoping for a better way that I can just add to my code though. If not, we will see what happens.